# Skip specific terms with google tranlsate API

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm using Google Translate API and I want to know how to make it "skip" some phrases which should not be translated.

I found that if I surround the phrase with <> it seems to be working:

```
client.translate('Hey friend, bring me a <cold beer>.', target_language='it', source_language='en')
```

Output:

```
{'input': 'Hey friend, bring me a <cold beer>.', 'translatedText': 'Ehi amico, portami un <cold beer> .'}
```

While if I remove the <> it's translated:

```
{'input': 'Hey friend, bring me a cold beer.', 'translatedText': 'Ehi amico, portami una birra fredda.'}
```

It this the right way to do it? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be using these [HTML tags](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions) as Translation API [doesn't translate any HTML tags](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text). The API is thinking that you're using an HTML tag when you're using the caret brackets within your request.

Comment: In the docs it says "This functionality requires the source text to be submitted in HTML." but the code above is still working without modifications. However, i noticed some differences in the translation between using <word> and <span translate="no">word</span>.

Comment: Regarding this behavior, I suggest opening a [bug report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) within the [Translation API Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187144&template=1011235) to receive clarification about this matter from its engineering team.